# CPU and Memory Usage

Tags: monitoring

I want to monitor the CPU and Memory usage for long hours and find the average of that on a Linux server. Can anybody help me to monitor it using a script. I want to know the readings for around 15-20hrs.

Comment: Check out nagios: http://www.nagios.org.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the sysstat package for that, it has, among others, the `sar` and `mpstat` commands that could be useful four your usecase...